# How to pass table value to the modal?

Tags: laravel

I actually have projects and modules table. When i click button, 
i want to get the data from model of that specific project. 
Here is my code :
this is my table where i want to show the data of modules that represent specific project.

```
 <table class="report">
      <tr>
        <th class="report-th"> Module ID </th>
        <th class="report-th"> Module Name </th>
        <th class="report-th"> Module Status </th>
      </tr>
      @if($modules->where('project_id','=',$project->id))
      @foreach($modules as $module)

      <tr>
      <td>{{$module->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$module->title}}</td>
      <td>{{$module->status}}</td>
    </tr>
     @endforeach
     @endif
    </table>
```

below is the code in controller:

```
public function show()
    {
        $sortBy = 'id';
        $sortDirection = 'ASC';

     if (request('sortby') || request('sortdir')) {
            $sortBy = request('sortby');
            $sortDirection = request('sortdir');
     }

     $projects = projects::orderBy($sortBy, $sortDirection)->paginate(6);


     $modules= modules::all();

     return view('tms.projects', compact('projects','modules'));

    }
```

Comment: Are u talking about saving the data ?

Comment: Thank you for the response, Bt i am talking about fetching data

Comment: $projects = projects::orderBy($sortBy, $sortDirection)->paginate(6);
 giving all projects data from project model, $modules= modules::all();  is giving all data from modules table(Model), Do you need the module data related to a specifc project(model) ?

Comment: If you want to get that specific project details, you need to pass `project_id` and then make a `where` condition to get the specific data.

Comment: yes, I only want to fetch model for the specific project

Comment: Thank you  Hiren Gohel  sir, Can you help me out in detail? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Have you `<form>` tag OR `<a>` tag to get the project details?

Comment: I haven't used any of these. I just used a model popup to view these data

Comment: Best practice is to use eloquent relationship and fetch data for project.

Comment: thank you for your response @Kul sir, But  I have used eloquent relationship.Even though I am getting all the modules value

Comment: As per your code in question, i didn't get how you want to show details!

Comment: I have a data table of projects in a view. And there is a button called view project details. If i want to view project details, the pop up modal must show the module detail in the table used in pop up modal.

Comment: See this link to get idea: https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/integrating-a-bootstrap-modal-into-your-laravel-application/

Comment: thank you for the link, but i didn't get anything from it.

Comment: You're talking about a popup modal but I can't see any code of it. Could you share the modal code as well?